# How to get All Recordtype Names in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, json

Can anyone help me with how I get the specific object's All Recordtype Names in Lwc.
I'm using the wire "getObjectInfo" method to get all info for object but I'm not getting how I iterate over "recordtypeinfo"(getting it from getObjectInfo method).

```
"recordTypeInfos": {
            "recordTypeId 1": {
                "available": true,
                "defaultRecordTypeMapping": false,
                "master": true,
                "name": "Master",
                "recordTypeId": "recordTypeId 1"
            },
            "recordTypeId 2": {
                "available": true,
                "defaultRecordTypeMapping": true,
                "master": false,
                "name": "XYZ",
                "recordTypeId": "recordTypeId 2"
            }
}
```

I'm getting above object from "data.recordTypeInfos".
Can someone help me to push name and id to one array.
ex.

```
arr.push({ label : "RecordTypeName HERE" , value: "RecordTypeId Here" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want to use `Array.prototype.map` to convert an Array from one type to another.

```
let arr = Object.values(data.recordTypeInfos).map(
  ({ name: label, recordTypeId: value }) => ({
    label,
    value,
  })
);
```

Where `Object.values` pulls out all the values in an object so you can work with them as an array, `() => ({})` is an arrow function that creates an object literal, `{name:label,recordTypeId:value}` is a destructuring statement that assigns `name` to `label`, and `recordTypeId` to `value`, and `{ label, value }` takes the parameters with those names and creates a new object. [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) itself creates a copy of the original Array, transforming it through the function provided as the first parameter.